# Why do I get a sharp pain in my shoulder when I do pike push-ups?

Tags: pain, push-ups, shoulder-cuff

I've been doing pike push-ups for weeks, but, for the past couple of days, I have been getting a sharp pain in my left shoulder when I do them. After checking my form, I have seen that it is proper. Why could I suddenly be having this pain in my shoulder? Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because any answer will be pure speculation. Contact your general physician.

Answer (score 2):

Go to therapist / doctor. If you don't want - try tests like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CyXq8pEoYnI) one - to identify your problem. Then read/watch/find out how to fix the problem. Usually doctor is much better option - like that two from video. In case of problems I would choose them, instead of trying fix something for myself.

Comment: Please do not answer off topic questions. You either feel it is worthy of being answered, or is off topic. Answering off topic questions invalidates the concept of "off topic".

Comment: Got your point. I've noticed that our page is in beta program because of not enough answers per question. But I agree with your point, and will do as you wrote. Thanks.

Comment: That isn't the only factor, there are also questions per day, visits, etc. We are close, but encouraging off topic won't help, unfortunately.